# What does 'they' refer to in the sentence?

Tags: pronouns

In the following sentence, what does 'they' refer to.

> While people are arguing how coronaviruses spread, they have spread around the world.

Comment: What is the source of the quote?  As written it is ungrammatical (spreaded is "not a word")

Comment: @ James K. I've edited it.

Comment: The sentence is poor English. The present continuous 'are arguing' is followed by the present perfect 'have spread'. Also there is, in the sense clearly intended, only one coronavirus.

Comment: The simple answer, setting aside quibbles with the sentence, is that "they" refers to coronaviruses.

Comment: It's not a great sentence because it is ambiguous. "They" could refer to either "people" or "coronaviruses." It would be clearer to say ,"While people are arguing about how the coronavirus spreads, it has spread around the world."